# How to preselect a country with the `country_select` helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, localization, country-codes, html-select

How is it possible to preselect a country in the dropdown list generated by the `country_select` or `localized_country_select` helpers? The following code nicely creates a list of countries, but the `:selected => :ch` part does not have the expected effect of preselecting Switzerland (ch):

```
<%= localized_country_select(:user, :country, [], :selected => :ch) %>
```

**Update:** the following seems to be a better choice for achieving this.

```
localized_country_select_tag(name, selected_value = nil, priority_countries = nil, html_options = {})
```

Comment: I have solved this by adding a `:default => "ch"` to my database.

Comment: Alternatively, use the `localized_country_select_tag`.